# No module named 'psycopg2' - how to use python library in an AWS Lambda with CloudFormation?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm writing a Lambda in AWS in a CloudFormation template.  It's a fairly trivial piece of code and looks like this:

```
  DbAdminLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
            import psycopg2
            import json

            def lambda_handler(event, context):

                print(json.dumps(event))
                ... do logic ...

                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, "UserCreatedOk", "CustomResourcePhysicalID")

      MemorySize: 128
      Description: create postgres roles / users
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
```

I am using the psycopg2 python module to talk to a Postgres DB.  The code is tested and working locally.

The lambda deploys ok, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'psycopg2'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

If as I fear this means the lambda is missing the psycopg2 binary, how am I supposed to make this code run?  Do I really have to build some binary and upload it to S3 or something?

Comment: Are you using layer with `psycopg2` or how did you bundle `psycopg2` with your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the layers feature, and I added the handy 3rd party psycopg2 layer from here:
https://github.com/jetbridge/psycopg2-lambda-layer

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know that particular library, but if your code requires any custom ones, you will need to build the package, upload zip to S3 and deploy it from there.

It is relatively trivial process, just keep in mind that any updates to lambda will require new zip file name, at cloud formation will not pick up the change otherwise.